# ROS Answers SE migration: Quadrotor GUI

Tags: ros, quadcopter, gui

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

Is there a good open source GUI for piloting a quadrotor based on ROS ?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214464/quadrotor-gui/) by [RRRoman](https://answers.ros.org/users/22867/rrroman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-07-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I do not know about any special GUI. If I would need it, I'd create a perspective for it in rqt.
Well the big question is, what do you need to show there?

Camera? -> rqt_image_view

Battery? -> multiple rqt_plugins available (unfortunately no standard one)

You could also add RViz to it to Visualize a 3D Model of the copter.

I wondered a bit myself and found that one:
http://wiki.ros.org/ground_station

Looks pretty useful I think, but I do not see if you can get the code.

Maybe you can get it here, but I do not know if it is really the same one:
https://github.com/muhrix/mav_ground_station/tree/master/ground_station

---

Originally posted by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) with karma: 1376 on 2015-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RRRoman](https://answers.ros.org/users/22867/rrroman/) on 2015-07-27**:
Hi, thank you for ground_station this is close to what I was looking for. As for your quesiton, all quadrotors are similar and data you want to see in UI is also similar. Image_View, battery, roll, pitch, etc. I want to make it as generic as possible.